# db2 query which shows records repeated for each value in another table

Tags: sql, select, insert, db2

I need to insert records into e.g. table 1 by creating a new instance of each existing record in the table for every record in one of the reference tables e.g. ref table 1.

So, for example...

**Table 1**

```
ID = 1, Name = John, Ref Table 1 ID = null
```

**Ref Table 1**

```
ID = 1, Name = Grade 1
ID = 2, Name = Grade 2
```

**Wanted result from SQL**
Table 1

```
ID = 1, Name = John, Ref Table 1 ID = 1
ID = 2, Name = John, Ref Table 1 ID = 2
```

or even

```
ID = 1, Name = John, Ref Table 1 ID = null
ID = 2, Name = John, Ref Table 1 ID = 1
ID = 3, Name = John, Ref Table 1 ID = 2
```

Is this possible using standard SQL?

Looking to get it all in one query as at the moment it looks like I'll have to repeat it for each ref table 1 record.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just do:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_1, tbl_2
```

Result would be:

```
tbl_1.ID    tbl_1.Name  Ref Table ID    tbl_2.ID    tbl_2.Name
1           John                        1           Grade 1
1           John                        2           Grade 2
```

Where tbl_1

```
ID  Name    Ref Table ID
1   John    NULL
```

and tbl_2

```
ID  Name
1   Grade 1
2   Grade 2
```

At last, just select the required columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

1. Create table for insert results:

   `CREATE TABLE to_insert(
      ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1)
     ,Name VARCHAR(100)
     ,Ref_Table1_ID INTEGER
     ,PRIMARY KEY(ID)
     ,FOREIGN KEY(Ref_Table1_ID) REFERENCES(ref_table_1)
   );`
2. Execute insert query:

   `INSERT INTO to_insert(Name, Ref_Table1_ID)
    SELECT t1.Name, COALESCE(t1.Ref_Table1_ID, rt1.ID) Ref_Table1_ID
    FROM table_1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN ref_table_1 rt1 ON (t1.Ref_Table1_ID = rt1.ID)`